# Assign a variable to a 'For' loop?

Tags: java, variables, for-loop

I am just wondering if it is posible to assign a variable to a WHOLE loop, as I am going to use te same exact one many times. I am a quite a rookie... Do not be to hard on me...

```
for (m = 0 ; m<=Student2.size()-1; m++)
{
    System.out.println(Student2.get(m));
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. You code is perfectly legal.

Comment: Are you refering to a [for-each loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)?

Comment: Putting in method is better idea :) Could would be simpler and easy to understand .:)

Comment: What I mean, is that I am using this exact loop many times in the code. Just wondering if there is a way to shorten it. Same as you do not write 5+5 all over,  you can just assign a variable: summ = 5+5...
I dont know if I explain myself properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html
You cant put your code into methods/functions that can get arguments an return values and this functions are code snippets you can call as much as you want. Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    doCalculation(3,5);  //call the method with two arguments
    doCalculation(7,2);  //call the method again with other arguments

}

//define a method in this way: visibilty, return typ, name, arguments
public static int doCalculation(int numb1, int numb2) {   
    int result = numb1 * numb2;                         
    return result;
}
```

Your function should look like(assuming the list hold objects of type string):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    printStudents(Student2);  

}

public static void printStudents(ArrayList<String> studentList) {   
    for (int m = 0; m <= studentList.size()-1; m++)
    {
        System.out.println(studentList.get(m));
    }
}
```

Comment: I see... but in my case, which would be the arguments?

Comment: in your case its the argument Student2 its an object, but i dont know the type. i think you called the class where student2 is an object of student class, right?

Comment: ah okay, and which type of data does this list hold? student objects? or strings?

Comment: i posted the function you need, assuming the ArrayList hold strings.

Comment: It contains Just Strings

Answer (score 2):

I believe the technical term for what you want is ["Extract Method"](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html):

```
public static void printStudents(Student Student2) {
for (int m = 0 ; m<=Student2.size()-1; m++){
            System.out.println(Student2.get(m));}
}
```

Then you just call this method where you want:

```
printStudents(x);
```

A side note: if `Student2` is a variable name then it should be lowercased.

Comment: The loop would be nicerthis way: `for (int m = 0 ; m<Student2.size(); m++){
            System.out.println(Student2.get(m));}`
}